# lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character / Using jsonlite in R

Tags: json, r, google-maps, jsonlite

lately i get this error if i try to parse a JSON response from Google.

```
lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not.
      [SICGCMCIAG?KAQ@I@KBKBGDGDOJ]\IHGDMDI@K@E?IAGAGAICGEGEIGIMOS
                 (right here) ------^
```

The String viewed in browser as send by google looks like this (i shortened it):

```
[SICGCMCIAG?KAQ@I@KBKBGDGDOJ]\\IHGDMDI@K@E?
```

this is the code i´m using

```
route_doc <- getURL(route)
route_response <- fromJSON(route_doc)
```

Somehow jsonlite hangs here.
What can i do to parse the response from google?

After investigating it a bit:
This crash happens if the poly line entry contains a backslash character

```
"polyline" : {
                    "points" : "qv{uHwlni@R?"
                 },
```

Thank you!

Update: i´m using this code to get an JSON response from google:

```
route_from="Köln"
route_to="Hamburg"

get_route_url<-function(origin,
destination,
avoid,mode,
alternatives,
key, 
return.call = "json")

{
  root<-"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" 
  u<-paste(root, 
           return.call, 
           "?origin=", origin,
           "&destination=",destination,
           "&avoid=",avoid, 
           "&mode=", mode,
           "&alternatives=",alternatives,
           "&key=",key, 
           sep = "") 
  return(URLencode(u))
  }


route<-get_route_url(route_from,
                     route_to,
                     "highways",
                     "driving",
                     "true",MYKEY)

route_doc <- getURL(route)

route_response <- fromJSON(route_doc)
```

and an Error for example in Polyline:

```
lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not.
          uHiani@@L@HBHBHBDDFDBDB`@@t@@\G"                      },    
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: use `library(googleway); google_directions(...)` or `library(ggmap); route(...)`

Comment: i will if the other solution will not work. I would like to construct the calls to google api myself. So this crash happens always on "polyline" entry.

Comment: can you post the code you're using to get the response from Google?

Comment: @SymbolixAU: i updated the question with the code that i´m using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's API returns the response in JSON, so you don't actually need to get the 'doc' using `getURL`, because `fromJSON` can read the JSON directly

So just call `fromJSON` on your `route` object

```
route_response <- fromJSON(route)
```

And to see the routes

```
library(googleway)
mapKey <- 'my_map_key'

df <- data.frame(polyline = route_response$routes$overview_polyline$points)

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
  add_polylines(data = df, polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]